# VarCmp returning 0x80020008 (Bad variable type)

Tags: visual-c++, variant, hresult

I'm trying to compare two `VARIANT` values in VC++ using the [`VarCmp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221006%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function:

```
VARIANT a;
VariantInit(&a);
a.vt = VT_UINT;
a.uintVal = 32;

VARIANT b;
VariantInit(&b);
b.vt = VT_UINT;
b.uintVal = 32;

HRESULT hr = VarCmp(&a, &b, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT);
```

I expected `VarCmp` to return `VARCMP_EQ` but it's actually returning 0x80020008, "Bad variable type." What's wrong with this code?

**EDIT**: I tried some other types based on Joe's comment, and got some surprising results.

Does not work:

- `a.vt = VT_UINT; a.uintVal = 32;`
- `CComVariant a((unsigned int)32);`

Works:

- `a.vt = VT_I4; a.lVal = 32;`
- `CComVariant a((long)32);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some interesting and possibly related comments at the WINE page: "Native VarCmp up to and including WinXP doesn't like I1, UI2, VT_UI4, UI8 and UINT as input variants. INT is accepted only as left variant."

http://source.winehq.org/WineAPI/VarCmp.html

Comment: Yup, all of the type that were not supported by Visual Basic.

Comment: I'm observing this behavior under Windows 7 as well.